# orthogonal group over reals as specific units in matrix algebra

Tags: group-theory

Consider the algebra $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers; its units form a group, $\mathbb{C}^*$. The algebra $\mathbb{C}$ is also a Euclidean space and the units of length $1$ form a group, $S^1$.

Let us go to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (or $M_n(\mathbb{C}$); this is also an algebra.

The units in this algebra form general linear group.

Can we recover orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ as subgroup of the unit groups of length $1$? I mean, is it true that 
$$O_n(\mathbb{R})=\{ A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}) : \| A \|=1\}?$$
Here norm of a matrix $A$ is as defined in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

If this is not true, then is the RHS (of above equation) a group, at least?

Comment: No. There are many non-orthogonal matrices whose norm is $1$.

Comment: OK; I don't know example of this, even it is simple (I am not too familiar with it); then what about my last question?

Comment: Tagging Lie groups seems awfully disproportionate to not knowing how to check if something is a group or not.

Comment: Beginner, you missed my point. If you can't check whether a subset forms subgroup or not, you are way over your head with considering Lie groups. It is much more advanced subject.

Comment: @uniquesolution, nor is it invertible. Not a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrices
$$A_k=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{k}\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
where $k$ is a positive integer. For each $k$ we have $||A_k||=1$, as can easily be checked, and each $A_k$ is in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ If $A_k$ was orthogonal for every $k$, then since $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, we would
get that $\lim_{k\to\infty}A_k$ is also orthogonal. But clearly the limit matrix is not orthogonal, because it is not invertible.

The set of invertible matrices whose norm is $1$ is obviously not a group. For example, the inverse of $A_k$ has $k$ instead of $1/k$, and the norm is $k$.